# Strange angle in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try using CNTRL to rotate an object in Unity by degrees, it turns not by degrees, but in a very strange way. The problem is only inside one project, in other projects everything is OK with Unity. Here is image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prWBg.png)

Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: you need to make a video/gif .. cos a snapshot shows nothning.. we have no idea what you're seeing